# Como recuperar o valor de um array

Tags: php

Bom tenho o seguinte array que esta dentro de uma variável `$resultado`:

```
{"result":[{"fone":"","email":"","id":1,"nome":"GERAL","token":"BE5DEA91EB28E98F053466E98082908545E3DCA5"}]}
```

Preciso recuperar o token.

Tentei assim, mas não deu certo:

```
$resultado[4]
```

Mas ele esta me retornando `s`

Comment: Isso aí é um json, precisa de um json_decode depois sim acessar a chave desejada.

Comment: @Sergio deu o seguinte erro `Notice: Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Backup.php on line 44

Notice: Use of undefined constant token - assumed 'token' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Backup.php on line 44
{"result":[{"fone":"","email":"","id":1,"nome":"GERAL","token":"BE5DEA91EB28E98F053466E98082908545E3DCA5"}]}rtoken`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) e depois acesse as chaves da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$json = '{"result":
    [{"fone":"","email":"",
      "id":1,"nome":"GERAL",
      "token":"BE5DEA91EB28E98F053466E98082908545E3DCA5"}
    ]}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo $array['result'][0]['token'];
```

***Exemplo:*** [*IDEONE*](http://ideone.com/l8wBHz)

Comment: deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Sua string está em forma de [JSON](http://www.json.org/), primeiramente utilize a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) para decodificar a string e converter em objeto, exemplo:

```
<?php

$resultado = '{"result":[{"fone":"","email":"","id":1,"nome":"GERAL","token":"BE5DEA91EB28E98F053466E98082908545E3DCA5"}]}';
$resultado = json_decode($resultado);
//Pelo formato do json você pode ter mais de um result
foreach($resultado->result as $res){
    echo $res->token;
}

//Ou simplesmente
echo $resultado->result[0]->token;
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/fRLXUv)**